# Compare 2 tables structure on mysql

Tags: mysql

This query does the job to compare 2 table structures on mysql:

```
select column_name
      ,max(case when table_name = 'table_1' then 'Yes' end) as in_table_1
      ,max(case when table_name = 'table_2' then 'Yes' end) as in_table_2
  from information_schema.columns
 where table_name in('table_1', 'table_2')
   and table_schema = 'your_database'
 group
    by column_name
 order
    by column_name;
```

but it converts column names to smalls caps, anyone know how tweak it to compare columns with mixed small and upper caps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html):

> "Column, index, stored routine, and
>   event names are not case sensitive on
>   any platform, nor are column aliases."